# Codeigniter route on button click

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter for this project

I have a button element as below

```
<div class=" pull-right" id="container">
    <button class="btn btn-info">
       <a style="text-decoration:none;color:white" href="">Guide</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

This button element is part of a div which is one of the results from the search. When I click on the button, how do i pass the information of the div to the controller I want? The information I want to pass is just the element id of the div which is "container".

Comment: So wheres the ID of the element? what element you talk about? the button?

Comment: sorry as edited above. id of the div which is "container"

Comment: I'll update my answer to use javascript ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do like that

```
<button class="btn btn-info">
   <a style="text-decoration:none;color:white" href="control/method/value">Guide</a>
</button>
```

In your class can do like that

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Control extends CI_Controller {

    public function method($value) {
        // Your value is in $value;
    }

}
```

[Update]
Getting the parent ID element dynamically

```
<div class=" pull-right" id="container">
    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="window.location='/controller/method/' + this.parentNode.id;">
       <a style="text-decoration:none;color:white">Guide</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the one I need!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : 'controller/method',
        data: {id : $(this).parent().attr('id')},
        success : function(data) {}
    });
});
```

In your controller:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);
```

Comment: @edelweiss Why that's is correct? I've created exactly what you asked.